# Python: Does not Increment Integer Value inside of String

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, increment

I have question about coding in Python, IDE I use is Pycharm Community Edition.

> **I have code like this**

```
i = 0
str_1 = """public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_""" + str(i) + """ {

public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_""" + str(i) + """_3(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }
}"""

for i in range(3):
     print(str_1)
```

> **And Current Output is like this**

```
public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0 {

public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0_3(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }
}
public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0 {

public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0_3(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }
}
public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0 {

public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0_3(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }
}
```

> `public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0` and `public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0_3(Context context)` do not change. The str(i) in the String does not increment.
>
> **I would like to get output like this**

```
public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0 {

public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0_3(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }
}
public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_1 {

public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_1_3(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }
}
public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_2 {

public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_2_3(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    }
}
```

> Is this possible to increment Integer value inside of the String??
>   I would love to hear your advice.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

That's because you assign it while `i` is 0. It won't update inside the loop. Try putting the string assignment inside the loop instead

```py
for i in range(3):
    str_1 = f"""public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_""" + str(i) + """ {

    public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_""" + str(i) + """_3(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
        }
    }"""
    print(str_1)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I have tried your code and it works perfectly what I'd desire for. Thank you very much